# Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:jar:1.12.169 when adding the AWS SDK for Java using Maven

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, maven, pom.xml

I am trying to add the amazon aws sdk to my spring project but every time I try and add it I get the same error. Regardless of version or other dependencies. I have tried to find a solution on here but have had no luck.
The only spring dependency I am using is Spring Web.

In the pom file-

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.12.169</version>
    </dependency>
```

Here is the full list of errors that occur in the pom file-
Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:jar:1.12.169

```
    org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:jar:1.12.169
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:255)
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:171)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.resolveCachedArtifactDescriptor(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:538)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.getArtifactDescriptorResult(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:523)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:410)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:362)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:349)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:254)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.collectDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:284)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:169)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.resolveDependencies(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:227)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:200)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:124)
        at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.readMavenProject(MavenImpl.java:649)
        at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.DefaultMavenDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies(DefaultMavenDependencyResolver.java:65)
        at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refreshPhase2(ProjectRegistryManager.java:544)
        at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.lambda$3(ProjectRegistryManager.java:508)
        at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:182)
        at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:156)
        at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:506)
        at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:358)
        at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:312)
        at `enter code here`org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.updateProjectConfiguration0(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:413)
        at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.lambda$1(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:362)
        at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:182)
        at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:156)
        at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:103)
        at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:1411)
        at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.updateProjectConfiguration(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:361)
        at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.updateProjectConfiguration(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:347)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.managers.MavenBuildSupport.update(MavenBuildSupport.java:87)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.managers.ProjectsManager$3.runInWorkspace(ProjectsManager.java:396)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:42)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
    Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:pom:1.12.169 failed to transfer from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:pom:1.12.169 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): The operation was cancelled.
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:424)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:229)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:207)
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:240)
        ... 33 more
    Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:pom:1.12.169 failed to transfer from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:pom:1.12.169 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): The operation was cancelled.
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.newException(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:225)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.checkArtifact(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:189)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.gatherDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:573)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:483)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:401)
        ... 36 more
    Java(0)
    Missing artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.6.4Java(0)
    Missing artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.6.4Java(0)
    Missing artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.6.4Java(0)
    Missing artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.6.4Java(0)
    Missing artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter- 
    logging:jar:2.6.4Java(0)
    Missing artifact ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.10Java(0)
    Missing artifact ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.10Java(0)
    Missing artifact org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.17.1Java(0)
    Missing artifact org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.17.1Java(0)
    Missing artifact org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.36Java(0)
    Missing artifact jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:1.3.5Java(0)
    Missing artifact org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.29Java(0)
    Missing artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.6.4Java(0)
    Missing artifact com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.13.1Java(0)
    Missing artifact com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.13.1Java(0)
    Missing artifact com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.13.1Java(0)
    Missing artifact com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype- 
    jdk8:jar:2.13.1Java(0)
    Missing artifact com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype- 
    jsr310:jar:2.13.1Java(0)
    Missing artifact com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter- 
    names:jar:2.13.1Java(0)
    Missing artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:2.6.4Java(0)
    Missing artifact org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:9.0.58Java(0)
    Missing artifact org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:9.0.58Java(0)
    Missing artifact org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:9.0.58Java(0)
    Missing artifact org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.3.16Java(0)
    Missing artifact org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.3.16Java(0)
    Missing artifact org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.3.16Java(0)
    Missing artifact org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.3.16Java(0)
    Missing artifact org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.3.16Java(0)
    Missing artifact org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.3.16Java(0)
    Missing artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:2.6.4Java(0)
    Missing artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:2.6.4Java(0)
    Missing artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test- 
    autoconfigure:jar:2.6.4Java(0)
    Missing artifact com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.6.0Java(0)
    Missing artifact net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.4.8Java(0)
    Missing artifact net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:2.4.8Java(0)
    Missing artifact org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:9.1Java(0)
    Missing artifact org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.36Java(0)
    Missing artifact jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:2.3.3Java(0)
    Missing artifact jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:1.2.2Java(0)
    Missing artifact org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.21.0Java(0)
    Missing artifact org.hamcrest:hamcrest:jar:2.2Java(0)
    Missing artifact org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:jar:5.8.2Java(0)
    Missing artifact org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.8.2Java(0)
    Missing artifact org.opentest4j:opentest4j:jar:1.2.0Java(0)
    Missing artifact org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:jar:1.8.2Java(0)
    Missing artifact org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.2Java(0)
    Missing artifact org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:jar:5.8.2Java(0)
    Missing artifact org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:jar:5.8.2Java(0)
    Missing artifact org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:jar:1.8.2Java(0)
    Missing artifact org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:4.0.0Java(0)
    Missing artifact net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.11.22Java(0)
    Missing artifact net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.11.22Java(0)
    Missing artifact org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:3.2Java(0)
    Missing artifact org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:jar:4.0.0Java(0)
    Missing artifact org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.5.0Java(0)
    Missing artifact com.vaadin.external.google:android- 
    json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1Java(0)
    Missing artifact org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.3.16Java(0)
    Missing artifact org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.3.16Java(0)
    Missing artifact org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.3.16Java(0)
    Missing artifact org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.8.4Java(0)
    Missing artifact com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:jar:1.12.169Java(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the AWS SDK for Java, then use the **[AWS SDK for Java V2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/home.html)**, not V1. Amazon strongly recommends using V2 over V1.

To learn how to use the AWS SDK for Java V2 in a Spring BOOT app, see this tutorial that uses several AWS services, such as Amazon S3 and Amazon Rekognition:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/example_cross_RekognitionPhotoAnalyzer_section.html

Included in this doc is the POM file that you need, the source files, etc.